# Which algorithm is being used in Android's spell checker?

Tags: algorithm, string-matching

I am doing some research on string matching algorithms. One of the most usable I came across is the one my cellphone uses (android 2.3.4 on SE xPeria neo v).

[image]

As seen in the screenshot, I pressed the characters `jiw` which are **near** the ones I wanted and it suggested correctly.

It seems like the algorithm is similar to [levenstein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) (distance between my input and the dictionary). Somehow the near characters have **some** value in the string-matching.

Any idea about the algorithm being used?

Comment: Can some of the close-voters explain why they think this is non-constructive? The question is very precise ("What algorithm is used?") and the source code for the system is publicly available so the question may be possible to answer.

Comment: +1 for a concise, answerable, interesting question.

Comment: Very Interesting programming question, +1 VOTE and good luck for your project

Answer (score 4):

I pulled the [Android source code](http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html) and looked for spell checking. I found this directory which seems to contain the sources you are looking for:

```
packages/inputmethods/LatinIME/java/src/com/android/inputmethod/latin/
```

The file `spellcheck/AndroidSpellCheckerService.java` looks like the one doing all the heavy work, but `Suggest.java` also seems to be involved in some way.

Answer (score 2):

This [excellent information retrieval book](http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/) has a detailed section on [Levenstein distance](http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/edit-distance-1.html), including weighted variations.  The weights could then be taken to be the distance between keys on your keypad.

Comment: Thank you @phs. The article gives much information and points me to my initial suspicion that Levenstein distance is the metric for string comparison in Android. But yet only suspicions..