# Spelling and grammar check on Android text messaging ?

Tags: android, algorithm, grammar, spelling, autocorrect

Im currently spending some time developing a text messaging application using the code here..

http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/sms-messaging-android

Now that the code was successfully compiled and running, i need to take this thing to the next level.. I would want to incorporate a spelling/grammar checking algorithm in java that automatically fixes the string/words that is gonna be sent to the recipient.. I badly need help :(

Comment: See the duplicate link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11066225/which-algorithm-is-being-used-in-androids-spell-checker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Damerau-Levenshtein distance seems like it'd be a good start for figuring out what words are close to what you're after:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damerau%E2%80%93Levenshtein_distance

But you'd need a dictionary to compare against I guess and it likely wouldn't really tackle grammar.